# Display list of icons in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I just started with flutter and I'm trying to display a list of icons so that the user can choose among some icons that I have previously selected.

I know how to display a dropdown menu item, but I'm looking for something in 2 dimensions, because the user will be able to select a lot of icons. It will also be nice to present this list without having to click a button. More like a scrollable box presenting the icons and being able to store the icon that the user selects. I don't need the exact code, I'll be happy with some pseudocode and what widgets will I need to use.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

My quick solution has a scaffold(you can change it to be any other Widget) where the body is a ListView and each item of the ListView is a ListTile which contains an icon from the list that was defines in the widget earlier (selectedIcons).
Not sure what you mean by store, but there is a onTap function that allows you to do whatever you need with the icon that was selected(I decided to print them here).

Something like this:

```
class IconSelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<IconData> selectedIcons = [
    Icons.favorite,
    Icons.star,
    Icons.access_alarm,
    Icons.accessibility,
    // Add more icons as needed
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select an Icon'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: selectedIcons.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(selectedIcons[index], size: 36.0),
            title: Text(_iconName(selectedIcons[index])),
            onTap: () {
              // Handle icon selection here
              print('Selected Icon: ${_iconName(selectedIcons[index])}');
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String _iconName(IconData icon) {
    return icon.toString().substring(12); // Remove the 'Icons.' prefix
  }
}
```